# AutoHotKey scripting to set condition on variable?

Tags: autohotkey

I am new at AutoHotKey scripting, I need some help to create conditions on variables before any of my hotstrings.

For example if the machine's **A_UserName** = A then **variable1**=chris, if **A_UserName=b** then **variable1**=mike, so on.

I would like to set it before any of my hotstrings. Here is a sample of my code.

```
if (A_UserName==A) {

variable1=Chris
}
else  {
variable1=Mike
}  

:#ct:: 

send, Closing ticket, please review data and let us know if you have any      
questions.Thanks %variable1%
return
```

The key is that i would like to set the conditions before any of my hotkeys or hotstrings so i dont have to use if else statements on all my hotstrings/hotketys.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (A_UserName==A)` suggests that `A` is a variable name.

In your case, you'd want to use

```
if (A_UserName=="A")
```

or

```
if A_UserName = A
```

or

```
A := "A"
; or: A = A
if (A_UserName==A)
```

PS. on your use of `==`, also note the following part of the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Operators):

> The operators != and <> are identical in function. The == operator behaves identically to = except when either of the inputs is not a number, in which case == is always case sensitive and = is always case insensitive (the method of insensitivity depends on StringCaseSense). By contrast, <> and != obey StringCaseSense. Note: A quoted literal string such as "55" is always considered non-numeric in this context.

Comment: Glad it worked. Since you're new here, please don't forget to always mark the answer **accepted** which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)